# SQL Server 2022 error: "Property Password cannot be changed or read after a connection string has been set. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)"

Tags: sql-server

> Property Password cannot be changed or read after a connection string has been set. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

I try to add SQL Server subscriber when I create new subscriptions and I check correctly name and password of subscriber but I get this error.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in whatever version of Management Studio you're using, rather than an error SQL Server produces. Ensure it's the latest version.

Comment: Both Publication and Subscriptions server Management Studio I use in version 19, and MS SQL Server in 2022

Answer (score 5):

I think SSMS 19 has a bug. I had the same issue then down graded to 18.8 and was able to finish setting up the subscriber.

Comment: Definitely a bug, I downgraded and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I use SSMS version 19 and it has the same error. I fixed it by re-downloading the latest version then over-installing it. It works for me.

Link to download SSMS the latest version: [Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16)